# Dynamic ChoiceField unable to be validated in form

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a form that's being given a dictionary of selection, it populates it correctly but on form submit it is not valid. When attempting to print `errors, non_field_errors` there are just blanks. When I am redirected to the form, now the choice field is populated by one choice and the csrf token from previous submit.

I've tried assigning choices in different ways such as `self.fields['calendar'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=choice_list)` directly assign in a different way. `self.fields['calendar'].choices = choice_list`, a custom validator that ignores the validation, and inline debugging.

Form model:

```py
class CalendarSelectionForm(forms.Form):
    calendar = forms.ChoiceField(label="Calendar")

    def __init__(self, calendars=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CalendarSelectionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        choice_list = [(calendar_id, calendar_name) for calendar_id, calendar_name in calendars.items()]
        if calendars:
            self.fields['calendar'].choices = choice_list
```

View:

```py
    if request.method == "POST":
        print(request.POST)
        cal_sync_form = CalendarSelectionForm(request.POST)
        print("Non-field errors " + str(cal_sync_form.non_field_errors()))
        print("Reg form errors " + str(cal_sync_form.errors))
        # print("Field val " + str(cal_sync_form.calendar))
        print("Field data " + str(cal_sync_form.data))
        print("Field fields " + str(cal_sync_form.fields) + " Form is " + str(cal_sync_form.is_valid()))
        if cal_sync_form.is_valid():
            data = cal_sync_form.cleaned_data
            print(data)
            return render(request, 'management/gcal_sync_dashboard.html')
        else:
            return render(request, 'management/acct_select.html', {'form': cal_sync_form})
```

Form template:

```html
<form class="form-import" action="/manage/gcal/sync/" method="post" id = "">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.calendar }}
    {{ form.errors }}
    {{ form.non_field_errors }}
    <div class="push clearfix"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 no-pad push"><input class="btn btn-brand btn-little button filson push-half" type="submit" value="Select email"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></input>
  </div>
</form>
```

The goal is to validate a posted form, the current print statements print out

```
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['sJHE8JJAzmeS0nRjaYZg5KdMlevJiInYY0G4YFJeITH1cVjciIdR1Dq1N28loUIL'], 'calendar': ['email@email.io']}>
Non-field errors 
Reg form errors 
Field data {}
Field fields OrderedDict([('calendar', <django.forms.fields.ChoiceField object at 0x117323080>)]) Form is False
```

Comment: You need to populate the `calendars` in the `Form` in case of a POST exactly the same way as you did in the GET, since you basically construct a "new" form in the POST call.

Comment: I populate the calendars like `form = CalendarSelectionForm(calendars=cal_dict)`, when trying to do the same it says `__init___() has been given too many values`

Comment: You should create the `CalendarSelectionForm` with `CalendarSelectionForm(calendars=cal_dict, data=request.POST)`, right now you pass `request.POST` as your `calendars` to the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view, you make a call to the `CalendarSelectionForm` constructor with `request.POST` as first *positional* argument. So that means that you call the `__init__` function, and `request.POST` is passed as the `calendars` parameter.

You can fix this by constructing your form with named parameters. You furthermore will need to pass the same parameter to `calendars` as you did when you rendered the form with the GET request, since otherwise the choices do not per se match, and the user might have picked an option that is in that case *not* available during the POST request. Like:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    cal_sync_form = CalendarSelectionForm(calendars=my_calendars, data=request.POST)
    # ...
```

with `my_calendars` the same value you pass when you constructed the form in the GET case.

Comment: The solution worked, that was the issue. As a side question does the form not pass the available choices and the selected choice to the form?

Comment: @Jacq: well a `Form` in Django is used to eventually render HTML (as well as performing validation). Although the choices appear in the HTML, if one makes a POST request, these do *not* appear in the POST data, hence Django can not "reconstruct" a `Form` based on the POST request, so no; that data is normally "gone".